# getting 'Cannot read property 'settings' of undefined' error when adding new rule using addMethod in Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to display a view in Popup to add data. Before displaying the view in popup window, I am trying to add jquery validation on a field. But its giving me error 'Cannot read property 'settings' of undefined'. Here is some piece of code.

This is view to be displayed in Popup on another page.

```
@model MVCGridAjax.Models.DomainMaster

@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "form1" }))

{

@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Player</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form>
                <input type="hidden" id="playerId" />
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DomainName)
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DomainName, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Enter Name" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DomainName)
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DomainDescription)
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DomainDescription, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Enter Description" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DomainDescription)
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" id="btnSave" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="Save()">Save</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

}

```
<script type="text/javascript">

jq(function () 

{

    jQuery.validator.addMethod("domainNameRequired", function (value, element) 
{

if (value == undefined || value == "")
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    })

    jq("#DomainName").rules("add", "domainNameRequired");

    jq("form1").removeData("validator");
    jq("form1").removeData("unobtrusiveValidation");
    jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.parse("form1");
});
```

And in Popup page

```
<title>Index</title>

<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<link href="~/Content/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<link href="~/Content/grid-0.4.3.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="~/Scripts/grid-0.4.3.js"></script>

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var jq = $.noConflict();

    function Add() {

        jq("#playerModal").load('@Url.Action("GetDomainVeiw")')

        jq("#playerModal").modal("show");
    }
    function Edit(e) {

        jq("#playerModal").load('@Url.Action("GetDomainVeiw")' + "/" + e.data.id)

        jq("#playerModal").modal("show");

    }

    function Save()
    {
        if(jq("#form1").valid())
        {
            alert("valid");
        }
        else
        {
            alert("Invalid");
        }
    }

    jq(document).ready(function () {
        grid = jq("#grid").grid({
            dataKey: "Id",
            uiLibrary: "bootstrap",
            columns: [
                { field: "Id", width: 50, sortable: true },
                { field: "DomainName", title: "Domain Name", sortable: true },
                { field: "DomainDescription", title: "Domain Description", sortable: true },
                { title: "", field: "Edit", width: 34, type: "icon", icon: "glyphicon-pencil", tooltip: "Edit", events: { "click": Edit } }//,
                //{ title: "", field: "Delete", width: 34, type: "icon", icon: "glyphicon-remove", tooltip: "Delete", events: { "click": Remove } }
            ],
            pager: { enable: true, limit: 5, sizes: [2, 5, 10, 20] }
        });

        $("#btnAddPlayer").on("click", Add);
    });
</script>
```

Add New Domain

```
<table id="grid" data-source="@Url.Action("GetDomains")"></table>

<div class="modal fade" id="playerModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">

    </div>
```

Comment: Look at the developers console in your browser and get the actual source of the JS error. Nothing you've posted here even mentions "settings", so how could you expect anyone to help you without the specific code that's causing the problem?

Comment: I found where is the problem. The problem is where we are adding rule to a particular element.

Comment: jq(function () 
{
    jQuery.validator.addMethod("domainNameRequired", function (value, element) 
{

if (value == undefined || value == "")
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    })

    jq("#DomainName").rules("add", "domainNameRequired");//here is the real problem.

   
});

Comment: jQuery.validator.classRuleSettings.domainName = { domainNameRequired: true } is the solution. But it is working only with className (here domainName) is class name. How to do it using element name.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer and that is

```
jQuery.validator.classRuleSettings.domainName = { domainNameRequired: true }
```

But the above answer is working with class name only. Is there any other way doing the same thing without using class?